# Which AT commands will be helpful to get SIM data?

Tags: com, gsm, at-command, telephony, umts

I want to retrive data from SIM through AT command like we get **IMSI** of SIM from command **AT+CIMI**
Similarly, we can get **CCID** of SIM from command **AT+CCID**

As we get all these details from SIM through AT command, i want to read elementary files of SIM like FDN, SIM capacity etc through AT command.

Can anybody provide the link/help for such information.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AT command set is defined in [3GPP Technical Standard 27.007](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/127000_127099/127007/13.05.00_60/ts_127007v130500p.pdf).

You can find information regarding FDN/capacity with the commands AT+CPBS and AT+CPBR (see pages 113-114).

Note that not all commands will be supported by all devices.